# How do I convert a "title" attribute to a mouse over event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a "span" element inside a "table" "td" element.  The span tag has a Title.

I want to get the title of that span tag and pull it out to make it the "mouseover" tip for the "td" element.

For example:

I want to turn this:

```
<td>
    <a href="#"><span id="test" title="Acres for each province">Acres</span></a>
</td>
```

Into this:

```
<td onmouseover="tip(Acres for each province)">
    <a href="#"><span id="test">Acres</span></a>
</td>
```

**EDIT:** I don't think you guys understand.  I am trying to put the onmouseover function into the "td" tag.  I am NOT trying to put it into the "span" tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your edit, you might check out jQuery's DOM traversal methods: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing

Something along these lines (not tested, I don't claim it's syntactically correct, just general ideas here)...

```
$("td").each(function()
{
    $(this).mouseover(function()
    {
        tip($(this).children("span").attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$("span#test").mouseover( function () {
   tip($(this).attr("title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant put a class on the td or select it in some way then start by selecting the span, then go to the span's grandparent and attach to the mouseover:

```
// get each span with id = test
$("span#test").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // attach to mouseover event of the grandparent (td)
    $this.parent().parent().mouseover( function () {
        tip($this.attr("title"));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll try it too :P

```
$("#yourTable").find("td").over(function()
  { generateTip($(this).find("span:first").attr("title") }
  , function() { removeTip() }
)
```

What this does:

- Get the table with id yourTable
- Select all its td
- insert a mouseover and mouseout event
- mouseover event : call the generateTip function with the title value of the first span in that td
- mouseout event : call the removeTip() (optionnal) function.

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery:

```
$('#test').attr('title')
```